# java/spring/tiles - elegant way to display data from multiple entities?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl, el

I have a java/spring/tiles application - basically a collection of forms, each with a backing entity object. At the end of this thing, a user will have filled out data for at least one entity or as many as five.

I need to display a summary screen, showing all the data a user entered. At this point, I'll know which objects a user has entered and I'll have access to them. I'm trying to come up with a clean way to display back all that data. My initial thought was to use jstl/el to dynamically spit it all out, but that got out of hand fast. Right now I'm looking at doing this for every single object:

```
<c:if test="${not empty object1}">
    ${object1.field1}
    ${object1.field2}
</c:if>
...
<c:if test="${not empty object5}">
    ${object5.field1}
    ${object5.field2}
</c:if>
```

I feel like having to account for up to five objects like that kind of sucks - it just seems clumsy (plus there's a lot more than two fields per object). Is there a better way to go about this sort of thing? I'm open to pretty much any solution really, I just went down the jstl path here because I thought there was a way to iterate over each object's fields, but if there is I couldn't find an example. So something slicker, or just bash through it with jstl like this? Any tips would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an interface (eg: `GenericFormObject`) which get implemented by all form objects, and have a method to display as html (eg: `getHtmlString()`).

You can then pass all form objects in a collection to your view, and in your JSP you just do something like this:

```
<c:forEach var="formObj" items="${formObjCollection}">
  ${formObj.htmlString}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I think I may try this long term - turns out I have to present this thing tomorrow, but I think this might give me greater control. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Changed accepted answer - the other solution was great for a quick-n-dirty (which I sorely needed at the time). This is definitely preferable as it's cleaner and easier to implement.


All my form objects are now extending an abstract class GenericFormObject with a getHtml method. Works like a charm. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

overirde toString() method for the object and return the way you want the fields to be shown. Then print the object itself.${objectX}. I believe you can iterate thru all your objects.

Comment: Ah, I don't know why I didn't think of that! Very simple, that should do nicely, thanks!